# including google+ api php client library without php.ini file

Tags: php, api, include, client, google-plus

I'm going to integrate google+ sign in with my website and I have now come to a point where I have to setup code on the serverside. Google has this page on how to install their php library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation. They recomend using php.ini to include thheir library but my web hoster doesn't allow me to edit php.ini.

I'm supposed to use this library to authenticate users, login users, logout user etcetera. As far as I understand.

How should I include all the necesarry dependencies without editing php.ini? Including the files individually with include or require didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the footer of the [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) in your question it states:

> Alternatively, you can set the same ini directive dynamically in your
>   code.
>
> `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/google-api-php-client/src');`

You can follow this step instead of modifying `php.ini`

Comment: Thank you for your answear but now when I try to use the library I get an different error. I am supposed to use this code $client = new Google_Client(); from [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)  but php returns with : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in (htmladress).

Comment: @pillikasnazsaxc You might want to try putting what you're passing to `set_include_path()` into `file_exists()` and making sure the directory is definitely correct. If this is readable you may have to open another question with that specific problem.

Comment: I got it to work now, had to install and use composer.